# How do I resize an image with PHP using imagecopyresampled and then get the contents

Tags: php, image-processing, amazon-s3, file-get-contents

I'm currently resizing an image and writing it to a file.  I've since had the need to store it in Amazon so all I need is the contents of the resized image.  Can this be done without first writing it to a file?

This is what my current code looks like:

```
    $success = $src_img && @imagecopyresampled(
        $new_img,
        $src_img,
        $dst_x,
        $dst_y,
        0,
        0,
        $new_width,
        $new_height,
        $img_width,
        $img_height
    ) && imagejpeg($new_img, $new_file_path, $image_quality);

    // Free up memory (imagedestroy does not delete files):
    @imagedestroy($src_img);
    @imagedestroy($new_img);

    $type = $this->get_file_type($new_file_path);
    $binary = file_get_contents($new_file_path);

    $image = $this->get_user_path() . $version . '/' . $file_name;

    $response = $this->S3->create_object(AWS_S3_BUCKET, $image, array( 'body' => $binary, 'contentType' => $type, 'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC));
    if ($response->isOK()) {
        // success
    }
```

How can I get the file contents without first writing it to a file?

Answer (score 2):

You need wrap `imagejpeg($new_img, NULL, $image_quality)` with output buffer commands:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($new_img, NULL, $image_quality);
$binary = ob_get_clean();
```